# How to print JSON data in PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to print these keys "name","adminName1","countryCode" from following JSON result.

```
{
"geonames": [{
    "adminCode1": "16",
    "lng": "74.19774",
    "distance": "2.95838",
    "geonameId": 1254611,
    "toponymName": "Thengode",
    "countryId": "1269750",
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 0,
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "name": "Thengode",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "countryName": "India",
    "fcodeName": "populated place",
    "adminName1": "Maharashtra",
    "lat": "20.51997",
    "fcode": "PPL"
}]
}
```

How to do it right way?

Comment: Decode your JSON into an array, get the keys with `array_keys()` and then grab the ones which you need

Comment: sir, if he need these key then why need to decode?? he alrready know them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `json_decode` and get the values. Because your `json_decode` function returns an object array you need to use `->` for accessing the values.

If your json string name were `$json`.

```
$arr = json_decode($json);

echo $arr->geonames[0]->name; //Thengode
echo $arr->geonames[0]->adminName1; //Maharashtra
echo $arr->geonames[0]->countryCode; //IN
```

You json decoded array would be:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [geonames] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [adminCode1] => 16
                    [lng] => 74.19774
                    [distance] => 2.95838
                    [geonameId] => 1254611
                    [toponymName] => Thengode
                    [countryId] => 1269750
                    [fcl] => P
                    [population] => 0
                    [countryCode] => IN
                    [name] => Thengode
                    [fclName] => city, village,...
                    [countryName] => India
                    [fcodeName] => populated place
                    [adminName1] => Maharashtra
                    [lat] => 20.51997
                    [fcode] => PPL
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: After trying your code, I Got this love letter from PHP :-D
PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: check online: [3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/efeeW)

Comment: Thanks Frayne and Dan :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple, Check it out.

```
<?php 

//just for error loggin
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

//json data
$json = '{
"geonames": [{
    "adminCode1": "16",
    "lng": "74.19774",
    "distance": "2.95838",
    "geonameId": 1254611,
    "toponymName": "Thengode",
    "countryId": "1269750",
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 0,
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "name": "Thengode",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "countryName": "India",
    "fcodeName": "populated place",
    "adminName1": "Maharashtra",
    "lat": "20.51997",
    "fcode": "PPL"
}]}';

//decoded json object
$jsonDataObject = json_decode($json);

//parsed variables
$name = $jsonDataObject->geonames[0]->name;
$adminName1 = $jsonDataObject->geonames[0]->adminName1;
$countryCode = $jsonDataObject->geonames[0]->countryCode;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$json = '{
"geonames": [{
    "adminCode1": "16",
    "lng": "74.19774",
    "distance": "2.95838",
    "geonameId": 1254611,
    "toponymName": "Thengode",
    "countryId": "1269750",
    "fcl": "P",
    "population": 0,
    "countryCode": "IN",
    "name": "Thengode",
    "fclName": "city, village,...",
    "countryName": "India",
    "fcodeName": "populated place",
    "adminName1": "Maharashtra",
    "lat": "20.51997",
    "fcode": "PPL"
}]
}';

$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data->geonames[0]->name;
```

Comment: try adding all the required fields...