# How to get data from third party api with PHP cURL?

Tags: php, curl

I want to fetch json data from one API but I am getting following error

> HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
>   Expires: -1
>   Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
>   X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
>   X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
>   Date: Wed, 27 Mar 2019 06:07:40 GMT
>   Content-Length: 36

```
{"Message":"An error has occurred."}
```

Its works with postman.Is there any syntax error while sending request?

This is my code

```
<?php
        //  Initiate curl
            //$post = "NoofAdult=1&NoofChild=1&NoofInfant=1&FromAirportCode=AMD&ToAirportCode=BOM&DepartureDate=21/06/2019&ReturnDate&TripType=1&FlightClass=Y&SpecialFare=0&AirlineType=A";
            $postData = array(
                'NoofAdult' => '1',
                'NoofChild' => '1',
                'NoofInfant' => '1',
                'FromAirportCode' => 'AMD',
                'ToAirportCode' => 'BOM',
                'DepartureDate' => '21/06/2019',
                'ReturnDate' => '',
                'TripType' => '1',
                'FlightClass' => 'Y',
                'SpecialFare' => '0',
                'AirlineType' => 'A'

                );
            $header_data = array(
                        "Content-Type: application/json",
                        "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
                        "InterfaceCode:1",
                        "InterfaceAuthKey:1",
                        "AgentCode:",
                        "Password:"
                    );

            $ch = curl_init();
            $curlOpts = array(
                CURLOPT_URL => 'http://stagingv2.flightmyweb.com/API/FlightAvailibility',
                //CURLOPT_URL => 'http://localhost/akshay/sampleapi.php',
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header_data,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_POST => true,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData,
                CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
            );  
            curl_setopt_array($ch, $curlOpts);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length: 0'));   
            $answer = curl_exec($ch);
            // If there was an error, show it
            if (curl_error($ch)) {
                die(curl_error($ch));
            }

            curl_close($ch);
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($answer);
            echo '</pre>';



            // Will dump a beauty json :3
            //var_dump(json_decode($result, true));

        //echo json_encode($outp);
?>
```

I need json output:

Comment: I think there is some logic issue, you may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37090168/how-to-print-json-data-in-php how to print JSON data

Comment: are you actually supplying values for the headers `AgentCode` and `Password`?

Comment: Postman can create PHP cURL code for you, so if you got your request working in there, I’d suggest you give that a try first.